# Раннее Возрождение и Р/ранний Ренессанс?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Они, эти оба двое, что - по-разному пишутся? О_о

> Сегодня базилика Санта-Мария-дель-Пополо славится как редкий для Рима
>   **памятник раннего Ренессанса**, а ещё и более поздними работами прославленных художников: новый обширный алтарь создает архитектор
>   Браманте, капелла Киджи принадлежит руке Рафаэля, а для капеллы Черазе
>   Караваджо исполнит полотна «Обращение Савла» и «Распятие Святого
>   Петра».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«... раннего Ренессанса, а ещё и более поздними работами прославленных художников»

... раннего Ренессанса, а также созданными позднее для этой церкви такими произведениями прославленных мастеров, как величественный алтарь Браманте, капелла Киджи Рафаэля и росписи в капелле Черази А. Карраччи и М. Караваджо — «Обращение Савла» и «Распятие Святого Петра».

Раннего (часть имени нарицательная) — со строчной. Художников? Безусловно, но Браманте выступает более в роли скульптора, архитектора.

Comment: "Плохое" согласование подмечено верно, но проблема не решена. "Славится как памятник, а также произведениями" (?!)

Answer (score 0):

Неудачное согласование: *славится как памятник, а ещё работами*.

Еще один неудачный варинат был предложен: *славится как памятник, а также произведениями.*

Мой вариант: **славится как памятник, а также благодаря произведениям.**